# Web application needs to open socket and support some protocol

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, web-applications, spring-mvc

Please help me to choose right (stable and safe) approach for my task. I have web application implemented with `Spring MVC` on `Apache Tomcat`.

To provide some service I need to make a connection to an external application over network. Also, I have to support specific network protocol with this software.

In this situation my web-app is a client, external application is a server. And also, external application could be run in many instances, so my web-app has to open many sockets.

Each connection should be supported asynchronously, so it seems to I should create a thread for each connection.

I thought I could create a `ContextListener` for dispatcher servlet of Spring and implement events of life-cycle: init and destroy. So here I could create and start my exotic service on initialization stage and shutdown it on destroy stage.

I realize that my solution might be not accurate enough. May be I should use `TaskExecuter` or something else. I'd be interested to know what would you advise me.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already using Spring MVC, it may be easier to simply use Spring's [lifecycle callbacks](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-factory-lifecycle) to do the initialization and the cleanup.

You could create a singleton service bean for each external peer (or multiple ones with different configuration settings if they would be identical otherwise) and use them as standard Spring-managed services.

Answer (score 0):

why are you trying make a Service for it? your web application (client) can simply use a Abstract Controller to call/request data from external application and show response on browser, upon any given event...

please be more specific about what you are trying to do

Comment: Thanks for answer! Interaction between web application and external application is being supported by specific protocol with own scenarios and state machine. This protocol isn't implemented with request-response model. User can watch only a piece of information which was collected through this protocol.

You mean `AbstractController`, is it about controller of Spring MVC?